# About と at the end of a phrase

Tags: particle-と, japanese-to-english, ending

In this song: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OYrbaZo-tdw  minute 2:13, the phrase reads:

> それでも何度でも　また芽を出すと

What does that と at the end mean for the phrase?

Comment: Oh it's so clueless... almost no way to know from the context. btw the link is blocked in Japan, working one: https://youtu.be/tLvAr9FuAS4

Comment: It seems to be a love song so, maybe it's short for と約束する

Comment: @OtheJared 離別の歌なのでそれはないと思いますよー

Answer (score 1):

From the entire lyrics and how they are sung, I think this と is a quotative-と that is connected to 分かってる. That is, 分かってる has two と/って-clauses.

> 春に咲いて　秋に枯れる
> それでも何度でも　また芽を出す**と**
>
> これまでじゃなく　これからだよ**って**
> **分かってる**

> **(I do know)** flowers bloom in spring and die in autumn,
> and they will sprout again and again.
>
> I do know it's not the past but the future that matters.

In this song, he has just broken up with his girlfriend. He still misses her, but he understands that time moves on and what's past can't be undone no matter what. In the first half of the song, he is basically shocked and regretting. In the above part, he is trying to convince himself that it's not the end of the world to him. In the last part, he has become somewhat positive.